# Multiple handlers in netty

Tags: java, proxy, netty

I would like to make a kind of logging proxy in netty. The goal is to be able to have a web browser make HTTP requests to a netty server, have them be passed on to a back-end web server, but also be able to take certain actions based on HTTP specific things.

There's a couple of useful netty exmaples, HexDumpProxy (which does the proxying part, agnostic to the protocol), and I've taken just a bit of code from HttpSnoopServerHandler.

My code looks like this right now:
HexDumpProxyInboundHandler can be found at http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/proxy/HexDumpProxyInboundHandler.html

```
//in HexDumpProxyPipelineFactory
  public ChannelPipeline getPipeline() throws Exception {
      ChannelPipeline p = pipeline(); // Note the static import.
      p.addLast("handler", new HexDumpProxyInboundHandler(cf, remoteHost, remotePort));

      p.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
      p.addLast("handler2", new HttpSnoopServerHandler());
      return p;
  }


//HttpSnoopServerHandler
public class HttpSnoopServerHandler extends SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler {
  public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, MessageEvent e) {
    HttpRequest request = (HttpRequest) e.getMessage();
    System.out.println(request.getUri());
    //going to do things based on the URI
  }
}
```

Unfortunately messageReceived in HttpSnoopServerHandler never gets called - it seems like HexDumpProxyInboundHandler consumes all the events.

How can I have two handlers, where one of them requires a decoder but the other doesn't (I'd rather have HexDumpProxy as it is, where it doesn't need to understand HTTP, it just proxies all connections, but my HttpSnoopHandler needs to have HttpRequestDecoder in front of it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not tried it but you could extend HexDumpProxyInboundHandler and override messageReceived with something like

```
super.messageReceived(ctx, e);
ctx.sendUpstream(e);
```

Alternatively you could modify HexDumpProxyInboundHandler directly to that the last thing messageReceived does is call super.messageReceived(ctx,e).

This would only work for inbound data from the client. Data from the service you're proxy-ing would still be passed through without you code seeing it.

Comment: I tried that, and it's much closer to what I want, but there is still a problem. Most of the requests are proxied correctly, but a few of them end up having the first few hundred bytes cut off which results in an invalid request to the backend server (and the page doesn't render or isn't returned at all). It seems like the HttpRequestDecoder is consuming some of the request before the proxy can send it on.

Comment: There could be a race condition between the code that writes the buffer to the network and the HttpRequestDecoder because they'll both be manipulating the same buffer object. Try sending either a wrapped version, or a copy of, the original buffer upstream.

Comment: It works when I modify HexDumpProxyInboundHandler to do outboundChannel.write(msg.copy()) or outboundChannel.write(msg.duplicate()), I'm not sure what the difference is to know which one to use, I posted another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215001/whats-the-difference-between-channelbuffer-copy-and-channelbuffer-duplicate