# What's the difference between ChannelBuffer.copy() and ChannelBuffer.duplicate() in netty

Tags: java, netty

What's the difference between ChannelBuffer.copy() and ChannelBuffer.duplicate()?

In [Multiple handlers in netty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197714/multiple-handlers-in-netty) I ended up coming across a problem that was fixed if I passed a copy of a ChannelBuffer or if I called duplicate on it, but I'm not sure which one should be used, and the javadoc doesn't help to know which one I should be using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`copy()` creates an entirely new buffer (byte-for-byte).

`duplicate()` creates a buffer which shares the original buffer's data, but with its own indexes.

Comment: When should I use one over the other? Eg in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197714/multiple-handlers-in-netty another handler seems to be be modifying the data while an async operation needs to read from the original buffer. Should I use copy() or duplicate()?

Comment: In that case, since you don't want to modify the buffer, you just want to get around having another handler on `HexDumpProxyInboundHandler`, then you only need to use `duplicate()`. Basically, use `duplicate()` unless you have a *need* to use `copy()`, since it creates an entirely fresh buffer.